# Localization between web application and silver light application with a common resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, silverlight-5.0

I want to do localization between web application and silverlight application. I have done localization in individual application, such as there is separate resource file for web application and silverlight application, I pass current culture from web application to silverlight object, than according to that culture resource file loads for silverlight. It is working fine.
But now our requirement has changed, we will have only single resource file and this resource file will be placed under Web application, so how silverlight app will pick up values from that resource file, how to achieve this.

Comment: Please suggest me how can i achieve this? I need to complete this as soon as possible.

Comment: There is no reply. :( Asking another question, I have 5 silver light projects which has individual resource file. Can anyone suggest me that can we use common resource file(in the form of dll) for all silver light projects instead of 5 resource files. Please share any link.